# Kendo Angular2 MultiSelect not binding to the returned response

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, multi-select, kendo-ui-angular2

I am building an Angular2 application where on one of the pages we have MultiSelect component. Upon typing minimum of 3 characters it makes web service call and starts to show possible matches. When we select items in MultiSelect and save; I am saving ID's of the selected items in a table which is there just to save selected id's from the multiselect. To retrieve the data back in my web api call I am returning the object type which has all the information to display what I had save earlier in MultiSelect which includes Code as well as rest of supporting fields in CPTdata

**My problem** is when I browse to the page where I have MultiSelect control the selected value does not bind/display to the control. I looked at the web api response and validate that the selected values along with supporting fields are present there. Is there some other step I need to complete in order to display the saved values that I had selected earlier ?

Here is my html code:

```
<kendo-multiselect id="txtCptCode"  #CptCodemultiselect
                             [filterable]="true"
                            (filterChange)="handleCptFilter($event)"
                             [data]="CPTdata"
                             [textField]="'Code'"
                            (valueChange)="CptValueChange($event)"
                             [valueField]="'CptId'"
                             [(ngModel)]="Model.CPTCodes">
         </kendo-multiselect>
```

Here is handleCptFilter

```
handleCptFilter(value: any) {
      if (value.length >= 3) {
          this.cptRequest.value = value;
          this._surgeryRequestFormService.getCPTByCodeOrDesc1(this.cptRequest).subscribe(
              data => {
                  this.CPTdata = data;
              },
              error => {
                  console.log("Error", error);

              }
          )

      }
      else {
          console.log("Do nothing");
      }
```

};

Here is CptValueChange

```
public CptValueChange(value: any): void {
    var _this = this;
    var model = new surgeryReservationModel();

    if ((this.CPTdata != null) && (value != null || undefined || "")) {
        for (let entry of this.CPTdata) {
            for (let selectedCPT of value) {
                if (entry.Code == selectedCPT.Code) {
                    var CPTDescription;
                    if (_this.Model.CPTDescription != null)
                    {
                        CPTDescription = _this.Model.CPTDescription;
                        _this.Model.CPTDescription = (CPTDescription + "\n" + entry.ShortDescription);
                    }
                    else if (_this.Model.CPTDescription == null)
                    {
                      _this.Model.CPTDescription = entry.ShortDescription;
                    }

                    //    _this.surgeryReservationModel.CPTCodeId = entry.CptId;
                    console.log("CPT Description is " + "" + _this.Model.CPTDescription);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        console.log("valueChange", value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [Kendo documentation notes](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/custom-values/),

> By default, when the Enter key is pressed or after the component loses focus,  values that do not appear in the supplied list of items are dismissed.

I had the same problem with `kendo-combobox`: populating the items in the control with an API changes if previously selected items display.  Change the search text and select something, and your selected items can disappear.

Short of:

1. using another Angular control that behaves the way you want, or
2. adding another control to display all the already selected items,

...the recommended Telerik approach is to use `[allowCustom]=true` then write a `valueNormalizer` function to add in dummy items that are missing.

```
// (pseudocode here)
valueNormalizer(text Observable<string>){
   if(text not in itemList){
      itemList.append({ text: text, value: text });
   } else {
      return {
      value: this.listItems[this.listItems.length - 1].value + 1, 
      text: text
      }
   }
}
```

I'm putting aside any discussion about whether this functionality makes sense - this is just how you could do it!